# Could I use Amazon Simple Notification Service to send web push notifications on chrome on an iOS mobile device?

Tags: ios, google-chrome, push-notification, notifications, amazon-sns

I need to send web push notifications on a mobile device through google chrome on iOS. Right now, this is not possible because webKit does not support service workers. So, could I use Amazon Simple Notification Service to send web push notifications on chrome on an iOS mobile device?

Many thanks!